# does the back-end storage support HDFS when using The Apache Ignite?

Tags: ignite

On the Overview site(https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/ignite-for-spark/overview), when you are using Apache Ignite, the back-end storage is HDFS.
I don't see how to use HDFS on this link ---> https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/external-storage

Comment: I don't see anything related to HDFS on either of these pages.

Comment: Take a look at the picture. What does the picture say about HDFS? On the Overview site(https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/ignite-for-spark/overview)

Comment: I guess that Ignite could have something to do with HDFS some time ago, but I don't remember that it was ever possible to store native persistence files in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite doesn’t ship an out-of-the-box implementation of its CacheStore interface for HDFS. You can implement it yourself or keep Ignite and HDFS in sync by other means: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/integrations/datalake-accelerator/getting-started

Comment: GridGain Data Lake Accelerator is an enterprise version of GridGain,That means Apache Ignite or GCE implements Persistence, either using Native Persistence or doing it yourself using the CacheStore Interface, right?

Comment: That’s right, but Ignite Persistence as a disk tier has many more advantages over any CacheStore-based integration: https://ignite.apache.org/arch/native-persistence.html